# class object definition - programming jargon:

Tags: language-agnostic, glossary, principles

what's the **definition** of class object that  has more than one version?
what's the name of object like that that has a default and than versions with more parameters?

say you have it like that:

```
public class object
{
   public object()
   {
      get sth; do sth;
   }
   public object(k)
   {
      get sth with k; do sth with k;
   }
   public object(k, n)
   {
      get sth with k; do sth with k;
      get sth with n; do sth with n;
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a class with multiple overloaded constructors?

Comment: There is no **official** definition for a jargon. You use it as you see fit. That's why we sometimes prefer formal languages to a jargon.